# Null terminated array in C++

Tags: c++

I want to create NULL terminated array in the constructor.

```
class Test
{
    char name [30];
    char Address[100]
};

Test::Test()
{
    memset(name ,0, 30);
    memset(Address, 0, 100);
}
```

Is this the correct way to initialize an array to NULL?

Is there any good alternative to this?

Comment: are you trying to replicate c-strings?

Comment: This hardly deserves to be called C++.

Comment: common Guys c string can be used inside C++ classes

Comment: You asked for a "good alternate" (*sic*). If you don't want to accept good advice, why do you ask for it? The code you've written is terrible, and you aren't doing anyone a favour by trying to salvage it. That's *not* how one writes C++, period.

Comment: please use consistent data member naming, ie "address".

Comment: @KerrekSB Yeah Its really My Mistake.you are right Kerreck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're planning on using C-style strings, you need only set the first character to a null terminator.

```
name[0] = Address[0] = 0;
```

But, in the long run, you will be better off using `std::string` instead.

Answer (score 5):

I'd probably do this:

```
class Test
{
    std::string name;
    std::string address;
};
```

Comment: I can't use STL.Suggest something without STL

Comment: @Chris_vr: How not? Imagine it's not STL, it's the C++ standard library.

Comment: @Chris_vr: -1 for failing to specify your arcane constraints in your question and then complaining about a perfect answer.

Comment: @Chris_vr: Why are you allowed to use some parts of the C++ standard library (`memset`) and not others (`std::string`)? Are you using C++ or not?

Comment: @NicolBolas I am not aware memset is function of C++.Anyway I need to change the code

Comment: @Chris_vr: Remember that [arrays are evil](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/containers.html#faq-34.1). Avoid them when there are better alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

The proper C++ idiom is to *value-initialize* your C-strings in your constructor's initialization list:

```
class Test
{
    char name[30];
    char address[100];

public:
    Test();
};

Test::Test()
  : name(),
    address()
{ }
```

This will have the net effect of all elements of `Test::name` and `Test::address` being set to `'\0'`.

Of course, it would be even better to avoid raw C-strings in the first place, but other answers have already made that point...

Comment: Thanks I guess this is better approch.

Answer (score 1):

To store strings, it's sufficient put first char to 0. I.e.

```
Test::Test()
 {
      name[0] = Address[0] = 0;
 }
```

If you want (for some specific your purpose) to fill the entire arrays, use sizeof to avoid hardcoding indexes.

```
Test::Test()
 {
      memset(name, 0, sizeof(name));
      memset(Address, 0, sizeof(Address));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want to do, but I should do:

```
Test::Test()
{
   name[0] = 0;
   Address[0] = 0;
}
```

in this way you can interpret your variable as empty string.